# Image carousel counter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to upgrade my image carousel/slider to Polymer 1.0. The logic is the same as I used with Polymer 0.5. However, when I use async to loop the method, the counter seems to be increasing by 2 or rather it adds 1, and adds another 1 before the async is triggered. What seems to be the problem here?

To make this more clearer:
Say I have a counter variable. In the old version, it would print like this.

```
1, wait 5 seconds, 2, wait 5s, 3, wait 5s,....
```

With the new version, it is:

```
1,2, wait 5s, 3,4, wait 5s,....
```

OLD VERSION (which works fine)

[https://github.com/DinethH/PWD-Groups-3.0/blob/master/elements/foreground-slider/foreground-slider.html][1]

NEW VERSION (w/ issue)

```
<body>
    <template is="dom-bind">

      <div class="toolbar">
        <button on-click="_onPrevClick">&lt;&lt;</button>
        <button on-click="_onNextClick">&gt;&gt;</button>
      </div>

      <neon-animated-pages id="pages" selected="[[selected]]" entry-animation="[[entryAnimation]]" exit-animation="[[exitAnimation]]">
        <neon-animatable>
          <iron-image preload sizing="contain" src="img/heroimage1@2x.jpg"></iron-image>
        </neon-animatable>
        <neon-animatable>
          <iron-image preload sizing="contain" src="img/heroimage2@2x.jpg"></iron-image>
        </neon-animatable>
        <neon-animatable>
            <iron-image preload sizing="contain" src="img/heroimage3@2x.jpg"></iron-image>
        </neon-animatable>
        <neon-animatable>
            <iron-image preload sizing="contain" src="img/heroimage4@2x.jpg"></iron-image>
        </neon-animatable>
      </neon-animated-pages>

    </template>

    <script>

      var scope = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');
      scope.selected = -1;
      scope.counter = 0;
      scope.ready = function() {
       //this.async(function() {
          this.nextCount();
       //});
      }

      scope.nextCount = function () {
          if (this.selected < 3) {
            this.selected = this.selected + 1;
          } else {
            this.selected = 0;
          }
          //console.log(this.selected);
          this.counter++;
          console.log(this.counter);
          this.async(this.nextCount, 6000);
      }

      scope._onPrevClick = function() {
        this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-left-animation';
        this.exitAnimation = 'slide-right-animation';
        //this.selected = this.selected === 0 ? 4 : (this.selected - 1);
      }

      scope._onNextClick = function() {
        this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-right-animation';
        this.exitAnimation = 'slide-left-animation';
        //this.selected = this.selected === 4 ? 0 : (this.selected + 1);
      }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: did you checked if the `ready` got called twice? I don't understand why it would happened, but it seems the only logical explanation I find...

Comment: You're right. It does get called twice within is="dom-bind". I wrapped them inside a custom element and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As in comment, it might be worth investigating why the `ready()` function is called twice inside the script.
Try to modify your code like this in script:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
    // your previous `<script>` code!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dom-bind` template is the only template instance that is late-bound. It's meant to mimic how a Polymer element behaves, but there are limitations - for performance reasons, Polymer 1.0+ as a framework does a lot of wiring during element registration time (ie. initialization time, as opposed to 0.5 where many things can be done on-the-fly). So I'm not sure `dom-bind` actually follows the lifecycle methods spec'ed out by shadow DOM definitions.

It is much better if you wrap your code inside a proper `dom-module` and call it from main doc - this ensures that things work according to spec.